# How to uninstall a hackage built by myself with cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

i use `cabal build` and `cabal install`  to install a hackage for a test

```
executable test-hackage
    main-is:          Main.hs

    -- Modules included in this executable, other than Main.
    -- other-modules:

    -- LANGUAGE extensions used by modules in this package.
    -- other-extensions:
    build-depends:    base ^>=4.16.4.0
    hs-source-dirs:   app
    default-language: Haskell2010
```

how can i uninstall it?

`uninstall` `remove` can not be used

Comment: AFAIK, this is one of the main limitation of `cabal` (and `stack`). `cabal` is able to download, build, and install new packages, but it can not remove them. It's not a package manager, but only a build tool.

Comment: The general philosophy seems to be: hard drives are big nowadays, so you just install and install and install, and if at some point you want to reclaim space you just nuke the entire packagebase (or even the entire disk) and start from scratch. Not saying I necessarily agree with it, but it does explain why this isn't prioritized by the Cabal team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour of `cabal install` is to install the executable to cabal's package store and [create a symlink to it](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.8/cabal-commands.html#cabal-install) in the destination directory (which, in Linux, defaults to `~/.cabal/bin`). If you just want to remove the executable from your path, deleting the symlink is enough.

cabal currently doesn't have a uninstall command. If there's a need to reclaim disk space, the most straightforward way to do so is deleting the store. Here is [what the User's Guide has to say](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.8/nix-local-build.html#local-versus-external-packages) on the matter:

> The global package store is `~/.cabal/store` (configurable via global *store-dir* option); if you need to clear your store for whatever reason (e.g., to reclaim disk space or because the global store is corrupted), deleting this directory is safe (`v2-build` will just rebuild everything it needs on its next invocation).